# gradle 2.0.0 beta 7 missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I keep getting this error. Any ideas?

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta7.
Searched in the following locations:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-beta7/gradle-2.0.0-beta7.pom
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-beta7/gradle-2.0.0-beta7.jar
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are referring maven central for finding android plugin artifacts, android gradle plugin is published at [jcenter](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view)

add `jcenter()` to buildscript.repositories block in your root build.gradle file.

It should look like as below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.X.X' // your verison

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i find out which version of gradle?